# How do Canadian banks manage their mortgage portfolio?

Tags: money-supply, mortgage

Firstly, I've read on CMHC website that only 30% of mortgages in Canada are securitized.50% of mortgages are on banks balanced sheet. And there is no reserve requirement in Canada (although there is capital requirement, banks stay between 4 and 5%). When I read online , it is said that banks create money by selling mortgage backed loans. So let say a bank sells a 100k mortgage. It takes the money from its own depositors accounts, from interbank loans and wholesale channels. Then, there is a black hole because it is said that banks will purchase Canadian gov. Bonds to back their mortgages. But with what money?? They already lent the money to mortgage clients? Please help me, I spent last night thinking about this and can't figure it out

Comment: It says on your profile that you are a financial planner for a Canadian bank. Wouldn't it be easier to just ask someone who understands the mortgage business in your bank? Anyone on Risk or the treasury with some experience should be able to answer this. It is not an economics (theory) question but a basic banking question.

Comment: It's assets (loans etc) vs liabilities (deposits, [covered] bonds etc). The amount of equity will ultimately determine your limit within legal frameworks (mainly Basel).